# Java | Finding specific lines from file

Tags: java

So I'm currently working on a project from school. I've saved data from customers in a .txt file in this format

```
-----
17-03-2020 15:49
WashType: De Luxe
ID: 1, Name: Janus Pedersen
-----
-----
20-03-2020 13:07
WashType: Standard
ID: 2, Name: Hardy Akira
-----
```

In order to thank customers for using this service, I'd like to give a customer some cinema tickets after each 10th purchase from us. To do that, I thought of reading this file again and look for their ID and count that but I simply can't make that work. My initial idea was something like the following, but it keeps giving me a null pointer

```
    String[] words;  
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("stats.txt");  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
    String s;
    String input = String.valueOf(washCard.getCardID());   
    int count=0;   
    while((s=br.readLine())!=null)   
    {
        words=s.split(" ");  
        for (String word : words)
        {
            if (word.equals(input))   
            {
                count++;    
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone who has any great ideas for this?
For things to be easier I've added it all to a github repo:
https://github.com/rasm937k/curly-broccoli

Comment: Can you share your stacktrace?

Comment: Can you also post your file?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the sample file data.

Comment: @Abra I've added it all to a repository at github https://github.com/rasm937k/curly-broccoli

Dont mind the shitty main class ://

Comment: The sample data you posted is misleading. I edited it by replacing it with an actual excerpt from the file you uploaded to Github.

Comment: Michał Kaciuba's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774498/java-finding-specific-lines-from-file/60774622#60774622) is still appropriate but you need to adapt it because it is based on the misleading, incorrect sample data you posted in your question (before I edited your question). By the way, any reason why you don't store your data in a database, rather than in a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is based on [Michał Kaciuba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774498/java-finding-specific-lines-from-file/60774622#60774622) but adapted to suit the actual format of your `stats.txt` file. I didn't know how to post this as a comment, hence I am posting it as an answer, but as I said, Michał Kaciuba should get the credit and I think you should accept his answer. Note that explanation of the code follows the actual code.

```java
String input = String.valueOf(washCard.getCardID());
Pattern pttrn = Pattern.compile("^ID: (\\d+)");
Path p = Paths.get("stats.txt");
try {
    long count = Files.lines(p)  //throws java.io.IOException
                      .filter(l -> {Matcher mtchr = pttrn.matcher(l); return mtchr.find() && input.equals(mtchr.group(1));})
                      .count();
    System.out.println(count);
}
catch (IOException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

`Files.lines(p)` creates a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) where every element in the stream is a line from file `stats.txt`, i.e. a `String`.

The [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) matches lines that start with `ID:` followed by a single space, followed by a series of one or more digits. The digits part is known as a capturing group because it is enclosed in parentheses.

The `filter()` checks to see if the line from the file matches the regular expression and if it does, the `filter()` then checks whether the "digits" in that line match your `input`, i.e. `String.valueOf(washCard.getCardID())`.

The `count()` counts all the elements in the stream returned by `filter()` and `count()` returns a `long`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 streams for that:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("stats.txt"))
        .map(line -> line.split(" "))
        .filter(words -> words[5].equals(washCardId))
        .count();
```

Also here's a nice tutorial on Java 8 Streams: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams

Comment: Great solution. As long as washCardId contains # this will work, otherwise you may need to replace the occurrence of #.

Comment: It doesn't contain an actual "#" it was just to simplify it. I'll edit OP